# How to change cultureinfo during runtime in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone, cultureinfo

In windows phone how can I change between 2 cultures inside the app, for example when user clicks on language setting inside app, it should change between English and Arabic, based on the Appresource files I created?

```
I have tried this on button click, but doesn't work:

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I run to similar problem once in the past. Maybe you havent added arabic as Supported Culture in the poject properties. This is what i did:

1. Edit .csproj in notepad
2. Add SupportedCultures tag inside PropertyGroup tag, and list languages your application will support

This is the sample format:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    .
    .
    .
    <SupportedCultures>
        en-US; ar-SA;
    </SupportedCultures>
</PropertyGroup>
```

That was work for me.